# Best approach to don't request same info over and over

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On my controller I have it inherit a **MainController** and there I override the `Initialize` and the `OnActionExecuting`.

Here I see what is the URL and by that I can check what **Client** is it, but I learned that for every Method called, this is fired up again and again, even a simple `redirectToAction` will fire the Initialization of the same controller.

Is there a better technique to avoid this repetition of database call? I'm using Entity Framework, so **it will take no time** to call the DB as it has the result in cache already, but ... just to know if there is a **better technique** now in MVC3 rather that host the variables in a **Session Variable**

sample code

```
public class MyController : MainController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}


public class MainController : Controller
{

   public OS_Clients currentClient { get; set; }

   protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
   {
        // get URL Info
        string url = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string action = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        string controller = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        object _clientUrl = requestContext.RouteData.Values["cliurl"];

        if (_clientUrl != null && _clientUrl.ToString() != "none")
        {
            // Fill up variables
            this.currrentClient = db.FindClientById(_clientUrl.ToString());
       }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // based on client and other variables, redirect to Disable or Login Actions
        // ... more code here like:

        //  filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "My");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

is it still best to do as:

```
public OS_Clients currentClient { 

    get {
        OS_Clients _currentClient = null;

        if (Session["CurrentClient"] != null)
            _currentClient = (OS_Clients)Session["CurrentClient"];

        return _currentClient;
    }

    set { 
        Session["CurrentClient"] = value; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you dealing with application security in that case I would suggest to create `Authorization` filter, which comes much early into the action. You can put your permission checking code over there and the framework will automatically redirect the user to login page if the permission does not meet `AuthorizeCore`.

Next, if the user has permission you can use the `HttpContext.Items` as a request level cache. And then you can create another `ActionFilter` and in action executing or you can use the base controller to get the user from the Httpcontext.items and assign it to controller property.

If you are using asp.net mvc 3 then you can use the `GlobalFilters` to register the above mentioned filters instead of decorating each controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @kazi - completely off topic, but you are my hero! Thx for Shrinkr and all your other work :) I still refer to your mvc best practices articles. Would be awesome it you updated for MVC 3 and what you've learned since the article was published.

Comment: @B Z Thanks for the complements :-)

Comment: @kazimanzurrashid but even if I put that in the `Authorization` filter, it will fire every time, even if I change routes... I was trying to avoid that, kind'a, fire once per request (no matter what route it takes ... no matter how many redirects it takes)

Comment: @balexandre Authorization filter only executes once per request, did you mean to exclude child requests?

Comment: yes, cause if you have `return RedirectToAction("...")` it calls a second time :(

Comment: @balexandre Redirect to action does not mean to execute another action in the same request. When redirected the asp.net framework sends redirect status code (301) to the browser and the browser issues a completely brand new request. This is no an ASP.NET related thing the whole web works in this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your base controller, you need to cache the result of the first call in a Session variable.

This makes sure the back-end (DB) is not called unnecessarily, and that the data is bound to the user's Session instead of shared across users, as would be the case with the Application Cache.